# Module Not Found

Tags: 20.04, package-management, kernel, scripts, pip

I want to run a script on my server and it gives me this error even though I installed Pyroxy ,proxy with pip3 and pip. But it gives me this error again, what should I do?

error:
from PyRoxy import Proxy, ProxyChecker, ProxyType, ProxyUtiles
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyRoxy'

Comment: Your question needs more info.  What script, it needs to be posted into the question.  The tags do not match the question kernel, package management, nothing in the question refers to them. Please EDIT the question.